# How to Convert Apache rewritemap from SDBM back to Human-readable Text

Tags: apache-2.4, rewritemap

I inherited old code where the prior devs had uses a number of large Apache rewritemaps for doing mass redirects.  Only problem is they only committed the SDBM-formatted (meaning a .pag and a .dir file) hash files as opposed to the human-readable text that created them.  httxt2dbm can be used to create a SDBM or BDB hash FROM the text file, but not the reverse.

I'm just trying to get the source file back that was used for these rewritemaps.  How can I go about this?

Comment: Probably a quick [perl script](https://perldoc.perl.org/SDBM_File).